# Why is sex pleasure giving activity but not childbirth?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, reproduction

Asking from an evolutionary viewpoint.

Sex is a pleasure giving activity so that it encourages reproduction and spreading of genes. But childbirth ,the most crucial part of the reproductive process, is equally opposite and many times hazardous to the health or even fatal to the mother.

why is that so? Not enough selection pressure (low death rate than succesful delivery rate)?

Comment: Maybe since abortion wasn't always an option back then?!

Comment: It's definitely not an adaptive trait to feel pain when giving birth - your nerves as electrical alarms don't care what is the cause of the pain you need. This has nothing to do with the fact that giving birth can be fatal to the mother. Apart from that, reproducing is the most important life function from the evolutionary perspective.

Comment: @probably yes but what i meant is why giving birth causes potential trauma and suffering to human body?

Comment: Nerves are electrical alarms for any type of damage. How would they recognize the pain comes from actually a useful thing?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is why birthing is not evolved to a level where it's no longer damaging and potentially fatal to the mother

Comment: Because it can't evolve like that. There is a trade-off between the size of the head (brain!) of the child and the risk for the mother. The flexible skull (fontanelles) is an adaptation to that.